# Decreasing and Increasing function

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sin x}$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{x}{\tan x}$ where $x\in (0,1]$, in this range whether f(x) and g(x) is increasing or decreasing.

I did this question up to this step
$$f'(x)=\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{(\sin x)^2}$$
$$g'(x)=\frac{\tan x-x(\sec x)^2}{(\tan x)^2}$$
After this I am clueless

Comment: Have you tried comparing the derivative to $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noting that for $x\in(0,1)$, $\tan x>x$, one has
$$ f'(x)=\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{\sin^2 x}=\frac{(\tan x-x)\cos x}{\sin^2 x}>0 $$
which implies $f(x)$ is increasing. Also noting that $\sin(2x)<2x$ for $x\in(0,1)$, one has
$$ g'(x)=\frac{\tan x-x\sec^2 x}{\tan^2 x}=(-x+\sin x\cos x)\csc^2x=\frac12\csc^2x(-2x+\sin(2x)<0$$
which implies $g(x)$ is decreasing.

Comment: What is wrong for the downvote?

Comment: I pressed downvote by mistake I changed it, if possible please incorporate the following modification $$ g'(x)=\frac{\tan x-x\sec^2 x}{\tan^2 x}=\frac{(-2x+\sin 2x)\csc^2x}{2}$$
which implies $g(x)$ is decreasing as Sin 2x<2x if $x\in (0,1]$

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi, you are right. It will be better. I changed.